# Disable harmful app

Tags: security

System update shows "disable harmful app", but it keeps coming up. I have a Micromax Canvas Infinity HS2. What can I do?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Micromax was just finding ways to make more money from its phones. So, what it starting doing was to throw ads and auto-install certain apps without the user consent. This backfired with many users complaining against them.

All this was done using the application which also checks for and provides phone system updates. While system updates are important, it will be too much to expect from them.

All this app is doing now is to show ads on your phone's various areas. That Play Protect warning is straight to the point. You should uninstall it, but even in case you fail to, there will be a *disable* button. Just disable it and get rid of annoying ads and this notification as well.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it unless you know what you are doing, the app seems to contain adware/malware.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall that app, unless it's integrated in system in that case you won't be able to uninstall it, but since it's prompting button to uninstall than it is probably uninstallable. It is probably Micromax bloatware.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy phones of the grey market, these are the sort of pop ups one could expect to see.

I would recommend downloading the norootfirewall app. That may help perhaps with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

System update / Updater application notifies only when an OTA update for the device is available. I have never seen such a message from stock system update app.

- Do you remember that, you have installed any third party app named system update? Or any bloatware app (eg: battery management like app).
- Some times opening a adware/bloatware website may have a chance to happen like this.
- Some devices have Security application that notifies to free-up space, uninstall unused apps, remove battery draining apps etc. But, those app definitely have name schemes with Security / Cleaner words in it.
- **Solution**: Please check all apps and uninstall apps which found to be unsecure. Install apps from a secure source like play store.